# customers table wont allow constraint

Tags: mysql

Hey so im trying to load in my database. The error I get is

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

I understand the error but whats the problem its having with the constraint?

Edit:

0

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
  KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
  KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `offices` (
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `territory` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`officeCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: If you don´t upload your **`employees`** table create statement it is very dificult to say

Comment: there  you go Sir

Comment: If you don't upload your `offices` table create statement it is very difficult to say

Comment: there you go Sir

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should create the tables in this order:

```
1.- Your table offices
2.- Your table employees
3.- Your table customers.
```

The problem is that you are trying to create first the table customers, and it ´s refering a table (employees) that does not exist.